# Maven: Does project inheritance or aggregation better support this scenario?

Tags: java, maven-2

I am porting a project from ant to maven.  The project consists of a core set of classes which gets jar'd and used by 3-4 other subprojects.  Importantly (I think?), the core jar has its own configuration that gets set at build time, and each subproject also has configuration set at build time.  In the old ant system, anytime I built one of the subprojects with something like...

```
ant -Dconfiguration=stage clean dist
```

...it would build the core jar using the same (stage) configuration, and copy it into the classes dir of the subproject's build.  I'd like to duplicate this functionality using maven.  From the reading I've done, it seems like Maven can handle this using either project inheritance or aggregation.  What are the chief differences between the two methods, and which would you recommend for the use case I've described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance is used for sharing common things between your projects, such as 3rd party library dependency or properties, or scm locations. Aggregation is used to build your projects as a group. You want aggregation, but that doesn't mean that you won't also be using inheritance to factor out common stuff.

Update: also keep in mind that maven is not just about building (unlike ant), it is about dependency management, so you could just create dependencies on your core and not use aggregation at all. You would depend on a particular version of your core. This however doesn't satisfy your requirement of building everything at once.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but given that the core has configuration of its own, and the configuration must match with the subproject or "bad things" will happen, it seemed like just straight up dependency wouldn't cut it.

Comment: So the configuration would probably go in the parent pom (inheritance), but you could still use dependencies.

Comment: I should elaborate; the core contains environment specific configuration (in stage, write to this DB, in prod, write to this instead).  The subprojects as well.  If the core artifact were configured for, say, production, and I built the subproject with stage config, and was just using dependency, I would end up in an invalid configuration.